Add undo button feature on iOS app
I noticed that the iOS app doesn’t have the “undo” button whereas the internet site provides it. 
Am I somehow missing to find it?
If this is not the case, would it be possible to add it in future releases?

Unfortunately the app is not currently under active development, so I doubt they will consider new features

The Android app doesn't have this button neither.

Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272229/please-implement-an-undo-button-in-the-edit-modus.
